# How to return something with a custom structure from data stored in two different tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table A (id, email, shipment_id, address, due_at) and a table B (id, email, timestamp, order_number, due_at). I'd like to return something like

```
| id | type | due_at |
| 1  |  A   |   ...  |
| 7  |  A   |   ...  |
| 5  |  B   |   ...  |
```

sorted by due_at ASC across both tables, for all records matching a certain email. I'm using PostgreSQL 9.5 - what's the best way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use UNION and ORDER BY

```
SELECT id, 'A' as type, due_at
FROM tableA
WHERE email = 'some@email'
UNION 
SELECT id, 'B', due_at
FROM tableB
WHERE email = 'some@email'
ORDER BY due_at ASC
```

You can also use UNION ALL instead of UNION to allow for duplicate values across the two tables.

Comment: Also you would need to add `WHERE email = 'the@address'` for both parts of the query.